# Referencing a table using caption package in a combined float (figure and table)

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, captions, subcaption

I am trying to create a float that contains three `figures` as `subfigures` and a `threeparttable`. In the end, I want to create one joint caption based on the example given in the `caption` package documentation. However, I do NOT want the caption above the table (because that defeats the purpose of the joint caption).
Not using the `captionof` inside the `table` environment makes it (apparently) impossible to reference the table seperately, however. So, how can I reference the table without creating the extra caption?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{andtable}{#1~#2 \& \tablename~\thetable} % combined Figure and Table
\begin{document}
    \section{some section}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
            \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
                \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example}
            \caption{Figure 1 of a couple more\label{fig:subfigure}}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{.54\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{threeparttable}[b]
                \captionof{table}{\label{tab:table}}
                \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.8\linewidth}@{}}
                    \begin{tabular}{cc}
                    A\tnote{1} & B \\
                    C & D\\
                    \end{tabular}
                \end{tabular}
                \begin{tablenotes}
                    \item [1]  Some footnote.
                \end{tablenotes}
            \end{threeparttable}
        \end{minipage}
        \captionlistentry[table]{This is a table.}\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
        \captionsetup{labelformat=andtable}
        \caption{Joint caption for the figure and the table.\label{fig:figure}}
    \end{figure}

    This is some text for referencing Figure~\ref{fig:figure} and Subfigure~\ref{fig:subfigure}.
    More text referencing Table~\ref{tab:table}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really want a joint figure/table caption?  It would be much easier to have one of each.  You could create a new float type (newfloat package) for joint figures and tables with a completely separate counter, or force tables and figures to use the same counter.

Comment: I realise that it is a bit unconventional. TBH this construct didn't cross my mind until I saw it in the `caption` package documentation. This way, I retain the entries in both List of tables and List of figures, and the arrangement saves me a lot of space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\captionlistentry` seems to create a reference, too, so you could put a `\label` right behind it:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{andtable}{#1~#2 \& \tablename~\thetable} % combined Figure and Table
\begin{document}
    \section{some section}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=.1\linewidth]{example}
            \caption{Figure 1 of a couple more\label{fig:subfigure}}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{minipage}[b]{.54\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{threeparttable}[b]
%%%             \captionof{table}{\label{tab:table}}
                \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.8\linewidth}@{}}
                    \begin{tabular}{cc}
                    A\tnote{1} & B \\
                    C & D\\
                    \end{tabular}
                \end{tabular}
                \begin{tablenotes}
                    \item [1]  Some footnote.
                \end{tablenotes}
            \end{threeparttable}
        \end{minipage}
        \captionlistentry[table]{This is a table.}\label{tab:table}
        \addtocounter{figure}{-1}
        \captionsetup{labelformat=andtable}
        \caption{Joint caption for the figure and the table.\label{fig:figure}}
    \end{figure}

    This is some text for referencing Figure~\ref{fig:figure} and Subfigure~\ref{fig:subfigure}.
    More text referencing Table~\ref{tab:table}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably the only position I didn't try. I typically use my `\label{}`s within the `\caption{}` environment, but a `\label{}` within `\captionlistentry[]{}` isn't referenced correctly. Definitely good to know.

Comment: I guess `\label` inside `\captionlistentry` does not work because it does not work inside the list-entry of `\caption[list-entry]{text}` either.